# Sending midi from AKAI -> Android -> Wifi -> PC/MAC DAW

Tags: midi, mac, pc, android, networking

all!

I would like to connect AKAI to Android, then play on AKAI, so midi signal would go via WiFi to PC/MAC DAW (like Ableton or FL Studio,...)

Other words: AKAI --usb--> ANDROID --wifi--> PC/MAC DAW

What software on Android side could do that?

P.S. I dont want to connect AKAI directly to PC/MAC.

Comment: You probably need to be looking at OSC [Open Sound Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control) implementations, though I can't help in recommending anything specific , as I don't have either Akai or droid; but I use to from my iPhone to Mac DAW

Comment: Thank you, Tetsujin, for advice.